# OR condition always false Flow

Tags: power-automate

I have a Flow and I cannot figure out why I keep getting false on the following condition. This looks for two thing, CorrectionsDate and CorrectionsMade. The CorrectionsDate return true or false correctly. The CorrectionsMade should be true if one of three different selections are made on the SharePoint List. I am looking for both conditions to be True. The OR condition never returns as True even if the appropriate selection is made on the SharePoint list. My understanding is that if "CorrectionsMade" equals Yes OR NA OR Referred to RD, that the OR condition would be True:

[image: Condition in Flow]

Below the input that is passed based on current inputs for "CorrectionsMade", in this case was "Yes". I would think this meets the OR condition, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

[image: Retured Inputs]

I added a compose for the variable "CorrectionsMade" and can confirm that when the input for the "CorrectionsMade" is "Yes" OR condition will still result in false.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, your OR statements are looking at a SharePoint List Item (I think) but above in your screenshots, you're showing a `Compose` operation.

Comment: @Skin- I used the Compose operation to see what was being passed since just looking at raw inputs stated the output was false. I was trying to see the specific inputs and based on that, the input meets one of the OR conditions.

Comment: Might better if you actually show the values of the relevant SP item.

Comment: @Skin Sorry for the late update. I think I may have updated the for the relevant SP Item. The condition should check for a date for a CorrectionsDate variable and this returns true or false appropriately. CorrectionsMade is a column. If the item from CorrectionsMade is Yes, NA or Referred to RD, then I want that or condition to return True.

Comment: That’s great but still can’t help, you haven’t provided the JSON that shows the values of the a relevant SP item. We’re punching in the dark here.

Comment: Ok, I'll look up how to find that, but that's an issue I'm having and why I used that compose to see what input was being passed. I don't see what is being passed but based on the compose I added, what is being passed is a value that should meet the condition of the OR condition.